# Iterator.continually vs while(..) in Scala

Tags: scala, iterator

```
    def task() {
      Thread.sleep(60*1000) // update lru cache every minute
      // do some compute-intensive task here to populate lru cache
      println("LRU Updated!")
    }

    new Thread {
     override def run = while(true) task()
    }.start
```

vs

```
  Iterator.continually(task()).dropWhile(_=>true)
```

have the exact same behavior. Are they equivalent under the hood as well ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "equivalent". They most definitely don't result in the same bytecode, the version with `continually` has much more overhead.

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator.continually` is useful to get an iterator that you can then use like a pseudo collection, for non side effecting results. Here you are doing a `println`, so `continually` is a nice sugar, but it doesn't really give you anything.
If you had something like:

```
def task() {
  Thread.sleep(60*1000) // update lru cache every minute
  // do some compute-intensive task here to populate lru cache
  "LRU Updated!"
}
```

To apply a side effect, you could still use thread, but you wouldn't be able to do much more (without more complex code).

```
new Thread {
 override def run = while(true) println(task())
}.start
```

If you wanted to transform the output, or push it to another call, or compose it, etc. then an iterator would be a nicer abstraction:

```
Iterator.continually(task()).map(x => s"$x Yay!").take(100)
```

But I guess that's not really what you want to do from your example.